# Iterating over associative array in bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I am renaming strings recursively using an associative array. Th array part is working, when I echo `$index` & `${code_names[$index]}`they print correctly. However the files are not modified. When I run the `find | sed` command in the shell it works however inside a bash script it doesnt.

Update

Also script runs ok if I just hardcode the string to be renamed: `find . -name $file_type -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/TEST/BAT/g'`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dir=$(pwd)
base=$dir"/../../new/repo"
file_type="*Kconfig"
cd $base

declare -A code_names
code_names[TEST]=BAT
code_names[FUGT]=BLANK

for index in "${!code_names[@]}" 
do
    find . -name $file_type -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/$index/${code_names[$index]}/g'
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare variable $file_type gets expanded by the shell. Double quote it. Variables are not expanded in single quotes, use double quotes instead. Note that it can break if `$index` or `${code_names[$index]}` contain characters with special meaning for sed (like `/`).

```
find . -name "$file_type" -print0 \
| xargs -0 sed -i "s/$index/${code_names[$index]}/g"
```

Comment: Thanks just found out that sed needs double quotes for variables. Thanks once again.

Comment: @homeGrown: Not just sed. Everything.